# Is there any way to make the following statement valid in C?

Tags: c, arrays, long-integer

Is there any way to make this statement valid in C ? I need to hold 18446744073709551615 elements in an array.

```
unsigned long long int array [18446744073709551615] ;
```

Comment: How much memory do you have on that machine? (How much memory is there on all machines in the world combined?)

Comment: a very bad idea, try using a DB instead.

Comment: Try `#define 18446744073709551615 1` or if you follow [Moore's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore's_law), wait about 30 years.

Comment: Does your computer have 130 petabytes of RAM?

Comment: @Thilo: the memory is actually irrelevant, the question is about addressable size. You could have an 8-bit system with a petabyte of memory but you could only address 2^8 elements of an array (in practice, probably less).

Comment: @DavidTitarenco: Okay, not relevant for compilation. But if you want to run that statement, too, you need a lot of memory.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your program will crash if this huge amount of memory is gonna allocated on stack because stack size is generally small. You can declare `array` as global (outside the `main`) to make it valid if that machine has memory greater than `18446744073709551615 * 8` = `147573952589.67642212` GB!

Comment: Why `*4`? Isn't  a `long long int` more than that? Especially on machines that can address that kind of memory space.

Comment: @Thilo; Ya. Missed that.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the size of the pointer on a specific machine/OS/platform; in other words, the machine needs to be able to access all elements. So theoretically, yes, it could be a valid statement. But it also couldn't.

Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, not even close.

18446744073709551615 is 2^64-1. `long long` is 64 bit wide, i.e. 8 bytes. To address your array you would need 64+3=67 bits address space. No current computer goes beyond 64 bit addressing. Furthermore even 64 bit computers can only address a subset of that. 
x64 for example only allows for 48 bit virtual address space and physically even less than that (AMD 48 bit, Intel less than that).

Even if there was a 128 bit processor, to handle your 2^67 bytes of memory (even if only virtual), you would need around 17000 of the biggest hard disk currently available (6 TB).